# Can someone please explain the に particle in this sentence: 'そして急ぐ君の目に焼き付いてはなれない'?

Tags: translation, verbs, particle-に

I have 2 question really: What is the に particle's job in this sentence?, And when I put this sentence on Jisho.org it identifies `焼き付いてはなれない` as 2 verbs, is it true?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sentence "に" decides the place the verb occurs. So the verb "焼き付いてはなれない" happens in/at/on/to "君の目"(Your eyes). If you can read Japanese this site would help you. http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/shuyoumokuji.html

And the verb "焼き付いてはなれない" indeed consists of 2 verbs. (Or could be 3) It is conbination of "焼き付く" + "離{はな}れる". (The word "焼き付く" could be separated in "焼く" + "付く")

"焼き付く" means "be imprinted" and "離れる" means "leave" but in this context it's more like "come out/off" or "fade away". So "焼き付いてはなれない" means "it is imprinted and doesn't fade away". Notice that "焼き付いて" ends with "-te" to combine with the next verb.

> そして　And
>
> 急ぐ君の*目に*　*In the eyes* of you hurries
>
> 焼き付いて　it is imprinted
>
> はなれない　and doesn't fade away.